# How to format this international phone number in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have an international phone number such as this:

> 0541754301

how can I format it to produce something like this:

> 0541-754-301

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use the `number_to_phone(number, options = {})` method from [ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.3.2/doc/index.html?a=M002505&name=number_to_phone)

However, the docs point out that this method formats a number into a US phone number (e.g., (555) 123-9876).

Instead you could use [this patch](http://github.com/seven1m/rails/commit/519d85dc528d75463f12fcbff642d23836475645) which adds the ability to provide number groupings:

```
:groupings     - Specifies alternate groupings 
(must specify 3-element array; defaults to [3, 3, 4])
```

So in your case you would call:

```
number_to_phone('0541754301', :groupings => [4, 3, 3], :delimiter => "-")
```

to produce:

> 0541-754-301

Answer (score 11):

Or, since you're not looking for anything fancy like parentheses or '+', but just hyphens between numeric groups, you can:

```
"0541754301".unpack('A4A3A3').join('-')
```

Comment: perfect! simple and easy. also works with whitespace as the delimiter.

Answer (score 10):

You can use regular expression to reformat the string. For the example you have given:

```
"0541754301".sub(/(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{3})/, "\\1-\\2-\\3") # returns: "0541-754-301"
```

Answer (score 3):

There's [phony](https://github.com/floere/phony) and [phone](https://github.com/carr/phone) gems available.

```
Phony.formatted('18091231234', :format => :international).should == '+1 809 123 1234'
```

or simliarly

```
phone.format("+ %c (%a) %n") # => "+ 385 (91) 5125486"
```